# Which browser settings might cause page load error after session timeout?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, internet-explorer-9, glassfish-3

my customer gets a page load error when he loads our web application after his session timed out. It only happens with IE9, it works perfectly on Firefox, meaning that he gets redirected to the login page with FF. When he deletes all cookies and the browser history, it works in IE9 again. I do not see any error message in the log file.

I cannot reproduce the error in my IE9 on the same server. Therefore I conclude that this problem might be caused by some settings in my customers IE9. The question is:

Which browser settings could cause a problem like this and how to work around that?

Additional information:

- The web app creates only one cookie containing the session id
- Server: Glassfish 3.1 With a Java EE application built with JSF 2.0 + Primefaces 3.0
- Client: Win7 + IE9, compatibility mode set to IE7

Comment: What exactly is the error message in IE9?

Comment: Is your customer using antyvirus software? If yes, ask him to disable browser plugin and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BalusC: it just says the page cannot be displayed. Nothing more.

Comment: @Piotr: We already tried that and did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting that caused this was the TLS 1.0 support in the IE9. It was disabled and when we enabled it, it worked.

The Glassfish server had support for TLS only, SSL 3 support was turned off. We solved the problem by turning on SSL 3 support in the Glassfish. Go to:

---

Configurations --> cerver config --> network config --> protocols --> http-listener-2

Go to SSL tab

check SSL3 enabled.

Save.

---

Alternatively you can enable the TLS 1.0 support in IE if you have the power to do that company-wide.

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers

Arne

Answer (score 0):

This is a session merging issue. We experienced the same problem with IE8.

Steps to recreate the issue:
Open the application in a new IE window and let it sit till session times out.

a) Open the application in a new tab or Minimize the previous window and open the same app in a new window.

b) If you have closed the previous IE window the IE process takes some time to die approximately 2 minutes. If you open a new url within this 2 minutes it is assigned the same process id.

And this happened only with IE8 not with FF or Chrome.

To solve this issue, you have to open the iexplorer.exe with -nomerge parameter.

More [info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately we do not have the possibility to change how the IE ist started for the whole company just because there is one web application that needs it.